# PrevR - could not find function "as.prevR"

Tags: r

I am trying to use PrevR (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prevR/prevR.pdf), and I am at the very beginning.

When I run this code:

```
install.packages('prevR')
par(ask = TRUE)
col <- c(id = "cluster",
          x = "x",
          y = "y",
          n = "n",
          pos = "pos",
          c.type = "residence",
          wn = "weighted.n",
          wpos = "weighted.pos"
)         
dhs <- as.prevR(fdhs.clusters,col, fdhs.boundary)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in as.prevR(fdhs.clusters, col, fdhs.boundary) : 
  could not find function "as.prevR"
```

I thought the function as.prevR was included in the prevR package I installed. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Place `library(prevR)` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: 'Beginning of your code' means actually the second line of your code. Once you have used `install.packages('prevR')` you probably won't need the line anymore and it can be deleted or commented out with `#`.